# `visitMethodCall` not getting called in lint

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, kotlin, lint

I have created a detector class with the intent to get the calling methods and do some operation on it.
But `visitMethodCall` is not called for the chained methods that I have added in the test case.

This is how the test case looks like

```
@Test
    fun `when tags work name is not referenced from RxWorkerTags enum an error is given`() {
        lint()
                .allowMissingSdk()
                .files(kotlin("""
                    package a.b.c.jobScheduler

                    import androidx.work.ExistingWorkPolicy
                    import androidx.work.WorkManager
                    import android.content.Context

                    class InboxSyncJob(private val context: Context) {
                        fun start(interval: Long) {
                            WorkManager
                                .getInstance(context)
                                .beginUniqueWork(
                                    "SyncJobService",
                                    ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE,
                                    getWork(interval)
                                )
                                .enqueue()
                        }
                    }
                """.trimIndent()))
                .issues(ISSUE_REFERENCE_RxWORKER_TAGS)
                .run()
                .expectErrorCount(1)
    }
```

**Detector class**

```
class ReferenceRxWorkerTagsDetector : Detector(), SourceCodeScanner {

    companion object {
        internal const val PRIORITY = 10
        private const val METHOD_BEGIN_UNIQUE_WORK = "beginUniqueWork"
        private const val METHOD_ADD_TAG = "addTag"
    }

    override fun getApplicableMethodNames(): List<String> = listOf(METHOD_BEGIN_UNIQUE_WORK)

    override fun visitMethodCall(context: JavaContext, node: UCallExpression, method: PsiMethod) {
        if (node.methodName == METHOD_BEGIN_UNIQUE_WORK) {
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

Ideally, `visitMethodCall` should be called for `beginUniqueWork`, but it is not working as expected.
Could someone please help.

Answer (score 1):

In tests Lint is not aware of what `androidx.work.ExistingWorkPolicy` and `androidx.work.WorkManager` are and cannot build an AST.

In order to tell Lint what these classes are, you should include their sources in tests classpath. There are two possible solutions.

#### Include library jar in your lint checks module resources

This method allows you to include the real source code of the library into the test, but may require you to import multiple jars (e.g. transitive dependencies).

Suppose the structure of the module looks like this:

```
lint-checks
└── src
    ├── main
    │   └── java
    └── test
        └── java
        └── resources
            └── my-lib.jar
```

In tests you should read `my-lib.jar` and include it as `classpath` file:

```kotlin
val targetPath = "my-lib.jar"
val producer = object : TestFile.BytecodeProducer() {
    override fun produce() = this::class.java.classLoader!!.getResourceAsStream(targetPath)!!.readBytes() // read bytes from resources
}
val myLib = bytecode(targetPath, producer)
TestLintTask.lint()
    .files(kotlin(file), classpath(targetPath), myLib)
    .issues(ISSUE)
    .run()
    .expect(expectedText)
```

#### Imitate the API of the classes you want to test

Basically, you just need to write the same code as the library to allow Lint to build *a similar to the original library* AST. This is relatively simple, but you can end up with rewriting whole library.

For your test it may be:

```kotlin
@Test
fun `when tags work name is not referenced from RxWorkerTags enum an error is given`() {
    val existingWorkPolicy = kotlin("""
        package androidx.work // make sure the package names are correct

        enum class ExistingWorkPolicy {
            REPLACE
        }
    """.trimIndent()))

    val workManager = kotlin("""
        package androidx.work

        import android.content.Context

        class WorkManager {

            companion object {
                fun getInstance(context: Context) {
                    return WorkManager()
                }
            }

            fun beginUniqueWork(
                s: String,
                existingWorkPolicy: ExistingWorkPolicy,
                any: Any
            ): WorkManager = this

            fun enqueue() = Unit
        }
    """.trimIndent()))

    lint()
        .allowMissingSdk()
        .files(kotlin("""
            package a.b.c.jobScheduler

            import androidx.work.ExistingWorkPolicy
            import androidx.work.WorkManager
            import android.content.Context

            class InboxSyncJob(private val context: Context) {
                fun start(interval: Long) {
                    WorkManager
                        .getInstance(context)
                        .beginUniqueWork(
                            "SyncJobService",
                            ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE,
                            getWork(interval)
                        )
                        .enqueue()
                }

                fun getWork(interval: Long): Any = Unit
            }
        """.trimIndent()), existingWorkPolicy, workManager)
        .issues(ISSUE_REFERENCE_RxWORKER_TAGS)
        .run()
        .expectErrorCount(1)
}
```